# WritableStringObjectInspector cannot be cast to BooleanObjectInspector

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hiveql

Every time i run a hive query which has an OR condition from my java program, I get the following error,

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableStringObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.BooleanObjectInspector
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFOPOr.initialize(GenericUDFOPOr.java:53)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF.initializeAndFoldConstants(GenericUDF.java:117)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc.newInstance(ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc.java:232)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory$DefaultExprProcessor.getXpathOrFuncExprNodeDesc(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:958)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory$DefaultExprProcessor.process(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:1175)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultRuleDispatcher.dispatch(DefaultRuleDispatcher.java:90)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatchAndReturn(DefaultGraphWalker.java:94)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatch(DefaultGraphWalker.java:78)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.walk(DefaultGraphWalker.java:132)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.startWalking(DefaultGraphWalker.java:109)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory.genExprNode(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:192)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TypeCheckProcFactory.genExprNode(TypeCheckProcFactory.java:145)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genAllExprNodeDesc(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10650)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genExprNodeDesc(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10606)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genExprNodeDesc(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10577)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genFilterPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:2736)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genFilterPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:2717)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genBodyPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8972)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:9884)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:9777)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genOPTree(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10250)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10261)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10141)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:222)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:430)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:305)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1123)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1110)
>       at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:99)
>       ... 26 more

But when i tried to run the following java program just to test the casting, it is cast successfully.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.BooleanObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableStringObjectInspector;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ObjectInspector[] arguments = new ObjectInspector[2];
        BooleanObjectInspector boi0 = (BooleanObjectInspector) arguments[0];
        BooleanObjectInspector boi1 = (BooleanObjectInspector) arguments[1];
        System.out.println(boi1);
    }
}
```

I have only one jar file which is  hive-exec-5.5.4 in my classpath. So i dont see any jar conflicts. Any other solutions?

Comment: Can you please update the piece of code  where you tried to use the WritableStringObjectInspector for casting?

Comment: The code is part of hive-exec-5.5.4.jar file.

"Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableStringObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.BooleanObjectInspector at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFOPOr.initialize(GenericUDFOPOr.java:53)" 

the exception occurs at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFOPOr.initialize(GenericUDFOPOr.java:53)

Answer (score 5):

My Bad,

The Right end of the OR clause in the query did not have a condition after key. I have solved the issue.